# Are methods of collection atomic operations in Java?

Tags: java, collections, atomic

Consider following methods of `ArrayList`:

```
addAll(Collection<? extends T> collection)
addAll(int i, Collection<? extends T> collection)
removeAll(Collection<?> collection)
retainAll(Collection<?> collection)
```

I want to know if these methods are truly atomic operations or not?

> Atomic implies indivisibility and irreducibility, so an atomic operation must be performed entirely or not performed at all.

Comment: id say they are. have a look here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29 so you can understand it yourself

Comment: No. I don't see why anyone would expect any of these operations to be atomic. Why would you think so?

Comment: "truly atomic operations" - what is an **un**truly atomic operation? The listed ones are certainly not atomic at all.

Comment: When you say atomic, do you really mean threadsafe?

Comment: @Fildor So we need to revert the changes if we intend to prevent partial additions or deletions?

Comment: @Henrik An atomic operation must be performed entirely or not performed at all. For example All items of collection should be added to the list or none of them. It would not be acceptable to add some of them and ignore some else.

Comment: I know what "atomic" means. I was struggling with "truly" ... :) But to answer your question: Yes, there is no built-in transaction system in ArrayList. In case of an exception you'd have to "clean up" the mess.

Comment: @a.toraby: I'm aware of that, but I agree with arcy on the question of why you would expect them to be atomic, so wanted to investigate whether a misunderstanding had taken place.

Comment: @Henrik As I said to Fildor It would be a nice feature to avoid partial additions and deletions.

Comment: That would indeed be a nice feature, but it also would have significant performance impact in cases where it is not needed. You could look for a replacement in some 3rd party libs like apache commons or guava or the like or you could subclass ArrayList and implement that feature yourself.

Comment: @a.toraby If you have a need for atomicity, you should perhaps look into finding a library with immutable lists, where any modification returns a new list instance. If something unexpected happens during modification, the creation and return of the new list will likely not happen, while leaving the original list unmodified, thus giving you a form of atomicity.

Comment: It's only useful at all if you're doing multithreaded operations, which isn't common and which generally requires careful handling anyway, and even then you don't always need the _same_ level of atomicity for performance.